# How to extend Symbolic Aggregate approXimation (SAX)

Tags: python, time-series

I would like to use more letters to transform the points of a time series. In Python the the letters are higher than 26 it gives me an error. My doubt is if there is a way of using more letters.
Thank you in advance.